# Task queues with Flask - Redis server quitting before executing

Tags: flask, unix, redis, fork, rq

I'm tryng to set up a redis server in order to run a simple task through RQ

I start a RQ worker from the VSC terminal, then open a new terminal, kick in a py shell session and type the following:

```
>>> from redis import Redis
>>> import rq
>>> queue = rq.Queue('microblog-tasks', connection=Redis.from_url('redis://'))
>>> job = queue.enqueue('app.tasks.example', 23)
>>> job.get_id()
```

before I end typing the last command, the first terminal with the rq worker has already raised an unhandled exception and quits. the attribute error is "module os has no attribute 'fork'"
I see that this is a UNIX thing, but I did set up a redis server through the WSL bash.
I would appreciatte any help into figuring out what is happening.
thanks!

i think so. this is the output to systemctl status redis on the bash:

```
 - ● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-02-21 16:04:31 -03; 2h 18min ago
          Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
                man:redis-server(1)    Main PID: 213 (redis-server)
        Status: "Ready to accept connections"
         Tasks: 5 (limit: 4584)
        Memory: 16.1M
        CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
                └─213 "/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ">
   
   Feb 21 16:04:31 Kaneda systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value
   store... Feb 21 16:04:31 Kaneda systemd[1]: Started Advanced
   key-value store.
```

Comment: Is you ssh connection live from your VScode to WSL while you run this in the terminal ?

Comment: i think so.just edited

Comment: ok the editing just sucks but the server is ready receive connections

Comment: Please make sure that all 3 things are being run in wsl. The redis-server, rq worker and your job provider. The problem seems like you are not running the worker in wsl and it is being run in windows terminal. Instead of vscode, try running everything in wsl terminal first to confirm that your setup works.

Comment: I was just now trying to do that from a wsl launched visualstudio, but I am having problems setting up the environment and else. anyway I would like to mark your answer as THE answer, thanks S_s !

Comment: after checking I have no idea on how to run nything but the redis server on wsl, can I ask you to point me in any direction? Other than installing python3, pip, and venv I have no idea how to go on

Comment: Well, I hope you are able to access wsl terminal in your windows machine. If you have that, setup a terminal multiplexer so that you can access open multiple terminal. You can use some like [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/downloads). Once done, open 3 terminals. Run redis server from one and you can keep tailing the logs in that terminal if you want. Create a venv in the second and run your worker there after activating the venv (I ideally do this with $python -m venv [dir-name]). And then run your job provider code in the third terminal using.

Comment: thanks! I am currently working on that! good riddance!

Comment: Awesome. post here if you face any issues further.